# Attempt to De-Reference a null object won't except data

Tags: apex, unit-test, null-pointer

I have an issue when I try to input data into a custom object.  On line 14 is where I'm getting the NullPointer.  System.debug(testAccount[0].name) outputs an account name created in line 8. But when I System.debug(rma.Account__r.name) it outputs null.  I'm at a loss on what I need to do.  I've searched through the many NullPointer answers, but nothing seems to be in the same context. Thanks in advance.

```
@isTest
public class TestRelationshipManagerAccountUtils {

    static TestMethod void TestRelationshipManagerAccountUtils () {
        string searchText = 'J Galt';

        TestDataFactory testFactory = new TestDataFactory(); 
        List<Account> testAccountList = testFactory.createAccounts(5);

        List<Contact> testContactList = testFactory.createContacts(5);

        Relationship_Manager_Accounts__c rma = new Relationship_Manager_Accounts__c();

        rma.Account__r.name = testAccountList[0].name;
        rma.Recruiter__c = testContactList[0].firstname;
        rma.Relationship_Manager_Contact__c = testContactList[1].name;
        rma.RM_Rank__c = 1;
        insert rma;
        System.debug('This is the account: ' + rma);

        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(rma);
        RelationshipManagerAccountUtils rmau = new RelationshipManagerAccountUtils(sc);
        System.assert(rmau != null);

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check to see if `rma.Account__r` is null?

Comment: As an aside, your final assert is nonsensical. Assuming you reach that line, the previous line has succeeded. The result of a new operation is never null.

Comment: BarCotter Yes rma.Account__r is null.  @sfdcfox I meant to remove that before the post I am aware that the assert isn't going to workout.  I'm going to do an assertEquals once I get this thing working.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to assign the ID to the field; this is how relationships are formed. Change the offending line to:

```
rma.Account__c = testAccounts[0].Id;
```

The same probably also applies to the two lines following: you probably mean to use the ID, not the name.

Comment: I changed to .id and still got the Exception.

Comment: @nwillard Did you change the __r.Name to __c?

Comment: Sure you can! You already have!